# Saving Coordinates Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: swift3, xcode8, geocoding

I am having trouble storing coordinates into a variable. I set a variable to type string! and then when the function runs the latitude and longitude are both stored separately. I am also performing a segue because the sign-up process I am using requires multiple screens.
The data then gets stored into firebase. All of my other fields get uploaded to firebase but, the latitude and longitude do not show up at all.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class SignUpLocation: UIViewController {

    lazy var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var latitude: String!
    var longitude: String!       
//Geocoding
    private func processResponse(withPlacemarks placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to Forward Geocode Address (\(error))")
            locationLabel.text = "Unable to Find Location for Address"

        } else {
            var location: CLLocation?

            if let placemarks = placemarks, placemarks.count > 0 {
                location = placemarks.first?.location
            }

            if let location = location {
                let coordinate = location.coordinate
                locationLabel.text = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
                latitude = "\(coordinate.latitude)"
                longitude = "\(coordinate.longitude)"
            } else {
                locationLabel.text = "No Matching Location Found"
            }
        }
    }






    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let thirdVC = segue.destination as! SignUpContact
        //:::: Initial Sign Up Values
        thirdVC.firstNameVar2 = firstNameVar
        thirdVC.businessNameVar2 = businessNameVar
        thirdVC.emailVar2 = emailVar
        thirdVC.passwordVar2 = passwordVar

        //:::: Second Sign Up Values
        thirdVC.streetAddressVar = streetAddressTextField.text!
        thirdVC.cityVar = cityTextField.text!
        thirdVC.countryVar = countryTextField.text!
        thirdVC.stateVar = stateTextField.text!
        thirdVC.zipcodeVar = zipcodeTextField.text!
        thirdVC.latitudeVar = latitude
        thirdVC.longitudeVar = longitude
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to your actual project so that I can see what is going on? It might be something as simple as a timing issue in that the latitude and longitude are not populated at the time of you calling the segue. Or it could be something else, but it's easier to detect if I can run the code to see what is going on.

Comment: I do not have a link to it, but it does appear to be a timing issue. I moved the segue to where it performed after the variable were stored. Although I did get it to work the coordinates seem to be very inaccurate. I came across an API called Smarty Streets which appears to be the best solution for geocoding in IOS as forward geocoding is not native to the Google Maps API on IOS.

Comment: Happy to hear that you got it sorted out :)

Comment: After doing further research, another API to look into is also MapQuest. Although they are old, they're pricing is pretty affordable and if you are only using the API for geocoding, the results are much more accurate than Smarty Streets.